# Supremum of set of products of elements of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $C = \{ab\mid a\in A, b \in B\}$. Show $\sup C \geq \sup A \sup B$.

I don't really get the point here. I understand it intuitively - if $A$ and $B$ contain big negative numbers, the supremum of $C$ gets big since the negative signs disappear but the suprema of $A$ and $B$ may be small if $A$ and $B$ only contain small positive numbers.

If $A = \{-3,-2,0,1\}, B = \{-5,0,1\}$, then $\sup A = 1, \sup B = 1$ and $\sup C = (-3)(-5) = 15$. So in this case, the supremum would be bigger. But I don't know how to prove this formally...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$
\forall a\in A\,\forall b\in B\,a\leq\sup A\text{ and }\,b\leq\sup B\text{ and }ab\leq \sup C.
$$

Comment: Oh yes, then it implies $\sup A \sup B \leq \sup C$. That's all?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. :-)

Comment: Wait: $a \leq \sup A$ and $ab \leq \sup C$ does only imply $ab \leq \sup A \cdot b$ but not $\sup A \cdot b \leq \sup C$, does it?

Comment: But if all terms are positive doesn't that imply this exact *opposite* that $ab \le \sup A\sup B$ so $\sup A\sup B$ is an upper bound of $C$ and so $\sup A \sup B \ge \sup C$ which is the *least* upper bound.

Comment: Yeah, that should be true @fleablood, if $A$ and $B$ are bounded from below by $0$, the inequality is an equality. But I still do not get the argument from before....

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $\sup A = 0$ or $\sup B = 0$ (wolog $\sup A = 0$).

If $\sup C < \sup A \sup B = 0=\sup A$ then for all $a\in A, b\in B$ then $ab < 0$.  So $a \ne 0$ but $a < 0$ so $b > 0$.  So for any $b\in B; b> 0$ we can find an $a \in A$ so that $\frac {\sup C}b< a < 0$ so $\sup C < ab < 0$ .  But $ab \in C$ so that's a contradiction.

==========

Case 2: $\sup A < 0; \sup B < 0$.

Trivial:  If $a \le \sup A < 0$ and $b \le \sup B < 0$ then $ab \in C$ so $\sup C \ge ab \ge \sup A\sup B$.

========

Case 3:   $\sup A > 0$ and $\sup B > 0$

If $0 < k < \sup A\sup B$ then $\frac k{\sup B} < \sup A$.  So there is a $k' \in A$ so that $\frac k{\sup B} < k' \le \sup A$.

And $\frac k{k'}< \sup B$ so there is $\overline k \in B$ so that $\frac k{k'} <\overline k\le \sup B$.  So $k <k\overline k\in C$.  So $k$ can't be an upperbound of $C$.  So either $\sup A\sup B$ is a least upper bound or not an upper bound at all[*].

So $\sup A \sup B \le \sup C$.

[*] $\sup A\sup B$ need not be an upper bound if we can have negative elements in both sets with absolute values that exceep the suprememums of the set.  If $a<0$ and $|a|>\sup A$ and $b< 0$ and $|b| > \sup B$ then $ab >\sup A\sup B$.

=======

Case 4:  one supremum is positive and the other negative (wolog $\sup A < 0$ and $\sup B  >0$ )

If $\sup C < \sup A\sup B < 0$ then $\frac {\sup C}{\sup B} < \sup A < 0$ and we can find an $a\in A$ so that $\frac {\sup C}{\sup B} < a$.  As $\sup B > 0$ there is a $b \in B$ so that $0 < b \le \sup B$ so $\frac 1b \ge \frac 1 {\sup B}$ and $\frac {\sup C}b \le \frac {\sup C}{\sup B} < a < 0$.

So $\sup C < ab < 0$.  But $ab \in C$ and that is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that $\sup A=:\sigma_A$ and $\sup B=:\sigma_B$ are finite. Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since multiplication is continuous at the point $(\sigma_A,\sigma_B)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$|a-\sigma_A|<\delta \ \ \wedge\ \ |b-\sigma_B|<\delta\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad ab>\sigma_A\sigma_B-\epsilon\ .$$
By definition of the supremum we can choose here $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. This implies
$$\sigma_C\geq ab>\sigma_A\sigma_B-\epsilon\ ,$$ and as $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we can conclude that $\sigma_C\geq\sigma_A\sigma_B$.

Comment: I don’t really get your continuity-argument. Can you explain it a little bit further?

Comment: @Thomas: See my edit.

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean with continuity of multiplication - what continuous function does that multiplication associate?

Comment: The function $(x,y)\mapsto p(x,y):=xy$ is continuous at all points $(x_0,y_0)\in{\mathbb R}^2$. This is a basic fact of real analysis.